# Magento 2: Where does the _request- parameter> getParam ( 'sort')?

Tags: magento2, request

I have a problem with an extension and it is that it returns the SAP data sorted in ascending order and I need them in descending order.

The list is obtained from a helper that passes as a parameter the value of

> _request-> getParam ('sort')

That value comes from the following line:

```
 protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set('SAP Online - ' . ucfirst(__($this->type)));


    if ($this->_request->getParam('filter') === '' && $this->_request->getParam('form_key') !== '') { 
        $this->_backendSession->unsetData('sap_gridfilter_' . $this->type);
    } else if ($this->_request->getParam('filter')) {
        $this->_backendSession->setData('sap_gridfilter_' . $this->type, $this->_request->getParams()); // 
    } else if (!!($this->_backendSession->getData('sap_gridfilter_' . $this->type))) {  // no tenemos params para filtrar, pero teniamos algo de antes
        $this->_request->setParams($this->_backendSession->getData('sap_gridfilter_' . $this->type));
    }

    $this->pageNumber = self::DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER;
    $this->itemsPage = self::DEFAULT_ITEMS_PAGE;

    if ($this->_request->getParam('page')) {
        if (!filter_var($this->_request->getParam('page'), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
            throw new \Exception('Page Number must be a number');
        }
        $this->pageNumber = $this->_request->getParam('page') - 1; //SAP WS pages start for 0
    }
    if ($this->_request->getParam('limit')) {
        $this->itemsPage = $this->_request->getParam('limit');
    }
    if ($this->_request->getParam('sort')) {
        $this->orderBy = $this->_request->getParam('sort');
    }
    if ($this->_request->getParam('dir')) {
        $this->orderDirection = $this->_request->getParam('dir');
    }

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

How do I change the value?

**Method:**

```
public function getRmaList()
{
    $data = $this->ws->getRmaCount
    (
        $this->fromRmaCode,
        $this->toRmaCode,
        $this->fromWebOrder,
        $this->toWebOrder,
        $this->fromRmaDate,
        $this->toRmaDate,
        $this->cardcode,
        $this->cardname,
        $this->repSales,
        $this->rmaStatus,
        $this->fromReturn,
        $this->toReturn,
        $this->motiveCode,
        $this->fromDelivery,
        $this->toDelivery
    );
    $count = ($data) ? json_decode($data, true) : null;
    $totalRecords = ($data && $count && $count['count']) ? $count['count'] : 0;

    // Update page if overflow page
    if ($this->itemsPage * ($this->pageNumber + 1) > $totalRecords && $this->pageNumber > 0) {
        $this->pageNumber = ceil($totalRecords / $this->itemsPage) - 1;
    }

    $docs = $this->ws->getRmaList
    (
        $this->getLocale(),
        $this->fromRmaCode,
        $this->toRmaCode,
        $this->fromWebOrder,
        $this->toWebOrder,
        $this->fromRmaDate,
        $this->toRmaDate,
        $this->cardcode,
        $this->cardname,
        $this->repSales,
        $this->rmaStatus,
        $this->fromReturn,
        $this->toReturn,
        $this->motiveCode,
        $this->fromDelivery,
        $this->toDelivery,
        $this->pageNumber,
        $this->itemsPage,
        $this->orderBy,
        $this->orderDirection
    );

    $this->docs = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $this->docs->setTotalRecords($totalRecords);
    $this->docs->setPageSize($this->itemsPage);
    $this->docs->setCurPage($this->pageNumber + 1);


    $data = ($docs) ? json_decode($docs, true) : null;
    if ($data) {
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $rowObj = $this->dataObjectFactory->create();
            $rowObj->setData($row);
            $this->docs->addItem($rowObj);
        }
    }

    return $this->docs;
}
```

Comment: $this->orderBy = "ASC" or "DESC" ....update Full code to work

Comment: @MR.RDNATH added the method where the list is obtained, it costs to find it.

Comment: $this->orderBy  -- this must be an property , not a function
check the initial value set in class file.
it must be write like this
protected $orderBy="Initial Value";
Find this.

Comment: @MR.RDNATH I had put it, now I have put the whole method

Answer (score 0):

*As per your requirement, i think you want to show pagination....
Try below code.....*

```
 public function _prepareLayout() {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle ()->set(__('Leader Data'));
        parent::_prepareLayout ();


        //echo $this->getleaderCollection()->getSelect()->__ToString();exit();
        if ($this->getleaderCollection()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','my.custom.pager');
            $pager->setAvailableLimit([5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,50=>50,100=>100]);
            $pager->setCollection($this->getleaderCollection());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        }
        return $this;


    }



    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
    public function getleaderCollection()
    {

         //get values of current page
        $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
        //get values of current limit
        $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest
        ()->getParam('limit') : 5;

        $company = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('company'))?$this->getRequest()->getParam('company') : '';
        $country = $this->getRequest()->getParam('country')?$this->getRequest()->getParam('country') : 'UAE';
        $sectors = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sectors')?$this->getRequest()->getParam('sectors') : '';
        $ownership = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ownership')?$this->getRequest()->getParam('ownership') : '';

        if($company):
            $filterarray =    array(
                                array('like'=>'%'.$company.'%'), 
                                array('eq'=>''.$country.''), 
                                array('eq'=>''.$sectors.''), 
                                array('eq'=>''.$ownership.'')
                             );
        else:

            $filterarray = array(
                                array('eq'=>''.$company.''),
                                array('eq'=>''.$country.''), 
                                array('eq'=>''.$sectors.''), 
                                array('eq'=>''.$ownership.'')
                             );
        endif;



        $this->_filterdata = $this->_leadercollection->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter(
                        array('company_name', 'country','sectors','ownership'),
                        $filterarray
            )->setOrder(
                'id',
                'asc'
            );




        $this->_filterdata->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $this->_filterdata->setCurPage($page);

        return $this->_filterdata;
    }
```

***Change the collection and param value as per your requirement.***
Also display pager need to call in ***phtml file***

```
<div class="row">
            <?php //if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
            <?php //endif ?>
        </div>
```